Formatting scales in ggplot() with scale_x_date(), but <date> class isn't being recognized
I'm trying to plot some data that was recorded minimum twice a week over ~ 30 weeks. While trying to plot using ggplot(), I'm attempting to adjust the x axis with a date scale so it doesn't have 30+ YYYY-MM-DD values on the axis.
Here is a code chunk for reference:
RA_summary_2024 |> 
  filter(`SLF Density` != "control") |>  
  ggplot(aes(factor(Date), y = `Proportion Deployed`, fill = `Treatment Type`)) +  
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Proportion of Population Re-Deployed") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.1, 1)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = `Treatment Type`), color = "black", method = "loess", se = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~ `Density Value`)

Unfortunately I'm getting this error
Error in `transformation$transform()`:
! `transform_date()` works with objects of class <Date> only

When double checking the data itself, the head() command indicated this code is in  format.
> head(RA_summary_2024)
# A tibble: 6 × 12
  Date       `Cage Number` `Treatment Type` `SLF Density` `Density Value`
  <date>             <dbl> <chr>            <chr>                   <dbl>
1 2024-07-18             1 native           control                     0
2 2024-07-22             1 native           control                     0
3 2024-07-25             1 native           control                     0
4 2024-07-29             1 native           control                     0
5 2024-08-01             1 native           control                     0
6 2024-08-05             1 native           control                     0
# ℹ 7 more variables: `Total Count` <dbl>, `SLF to Deploy` <dbl>,
#   `Proportion Deployed` <dbl>, `4th Instar` <dbl>, `Adult (Male)` <dbl>,
#   `Adult (Female)` <dbl>, `Adult (Unable to Determine Sex)` <dbl>

When attempting to resolve this, I tried forcing Rstudio's hand with a mutate() & as.Date() function:
RA_summary_2024 |> 
+   filter(`SLF Density` != "control") |>  
+   mutate(`Date` = as.Date(`Date`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) |> 
+   ggplot(aes(factor(Date), y = `Proportion Deployed`, fill = `Treatment Type`)) +  
+   theme_minimal() + 
+   labs(x = "Date", y = "Proportion of Population Re-Deployed") +
+   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B") +
+   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.1, 1)) +
+   geom_smooth(aes(group = `Treatment Type`), color = "black", method = "loess", se = TRUE) +
+   facet_wrap(~ `Density Value`)
Error in `transformation$transform()`:
! `transform_date()` works with objects of class <Date> only

The error still occurred. Any insights?

When you use aes(factor(Date)) you are undoing your work to set up the variable as a Date. The factor function will coerce it into a variable of type factor.
Simply using:
... |>
  ggplot(aes(Date, `Proportion Deployed`, fill = `Treatment Type`)) +
...

should resolve the issue.
In the future, try to make your example reproducible by including some data in the question using dput, thanks.
